# Display number list in this format django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to display my parsed result in the django template but at the moment, the code and result I have is as follows and I can't think of something else.

I am struggling to have the next five result on the next line.

**My code**

```
{% for number in numbers %}
  {%if not number|divisibleby:"6" %}
    <span>{{ number }}</span>
  {% else %}
    <div>{{ number }}</div>
    <p></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**The current result**

```
1   2   3   4   5
6
7   8   9   10  11
12
13  14  15  16  17
18
19  20
```

**My expected result** should look similar to

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
16  17  18  19  20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the `<div>` element. If you replace it with `<span>` and leave `<p>` unchanged it will be ok:

```
{% for number in numbers %}
    <span>{{ number }}</span>
  {%if number|divisibleby:"6" %}
    <p></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[Working fiddle of rendered html](https://jsfiddle.net/Wtower/Lx6a4vqa/).

Alternatively, this is what I would do as I don't like the `<p>` element of there:

```
<div>
{% for number in numbers %}
    <span>{{ number }}</span>
  {%if number|divisibleby:"6" %}
    </div><div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need django here? CSS3 has `:nth-child` pseudo class which does what you want

```
<span>1</span>....<span>n</span>
```

css

```
span {float:left}
span:nth-child(5n):after {clear:left}
```

But if you really need another way try this

```
{%if number|divisibleby:"5" %}
    <span>{{ number }}</span><p></p>
  {% else %}
    <span>{{ number }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I found out using bootstrap helped fixed all of this without the need for the `{% if number|divisibleby %}` part when the code is enclosed in a `row` class and `col-sm`